# Problem with a block of IF ELSE IF block in Google-Apps Script

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a long-running personal budget sheet that I started tinkering with as a way to learn more Google-Apps Script and whatnot. I have a basic/test version of the sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12abf7Cczjm9FaMnJV3V3jbePRUWVrGebJWpWh2SusJE/edit?usp=sharing

In any event, I have been working on the "Not Monthly Subscriptions & Such" section (I25:M43 on the Budget sheet) and had originally set it to only have Annual subscriptions. The script would trigger when the checkbox in the >> column was ticked and it would move the relevant data to the Working Area part of the sheet and increment the year--and that is functioning great in my "Prod" copy of the sheet.

I realized that there would be some other ways these items might occur, so I am trying to add a block of IF Else IF statements to handle the different types of schedules. The functionality is part of an onEdit() function in the script, but the relevant bit starts on line 59. Here is a copy of what is there:

```
//Add non-monthly items to working area
    if(col == 12 && row > 26 && row < 44 && range.isChecked()){
      var bill = range.offset(0,-3).getValue();
      var dbill = range.offset(0, -1).getDisplayValue();
      var amt = range.offset(0,1).getValue();
      var due = range.offset(0, -1).getValue();
      var type = range.offset(0,-2).getValue();
      var annual = "Annual";
      var w12 = "12 Weeks";
      var qtr = "Quarterly";
      var bia = "Bi-Annual";
      var once = "Once";

      Bu.getRange('P41').setValue(`${bill} (${dbill})`);
      Bu.getRange('R41').setValue(amt);
      
      if(type.getValue() == w12){
        due.setDate(due.getDate() + 84);
        range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due);
      }else if(type.getValue() == annual){
        due.setFullYear(due.getFullYear() + 1);
        range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due);
      }else if(type.getValue() == qtr){
        due.setMonth(due.getMonth() + 3);
        range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due);
      }else if(type.getValue() == bia){
        due.setMonth(due.getMonth() + 6);
        range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due);
      }else if(type.getValue() == once){
        range.offset(0,-3).clear;
        range.offset(0,-2).clear;
        range.offset(0,-1).clear;
        range.offset(0,1).clear;
      }
      
      range.uncheck();
      SubSort();   
      BillSort();
    }
```

Everything seems to work fine up to the first IF statement, at which point it just seems to abort. Any help or advice is appreciated!

Comment: Since the example is not reproducible and we don't have you data, it's kind of hard to help.  It's timer to learn how to use the debugger

Comment: My understanding about the debugger in this case is that it isn't going to be much help, as it is part of an onEdit function and requires the data surrounding the edit that triggers it. 

As for not having the data, I provided an editable version of the sheet complete with the script available via the link, so anyone with that link has the exact data and everything I am working with. 

Thank you, though.

Comment: Yeah but I wont follow links to spreadsheet in google accounts because it exposes my email.  so if you can't post the data in a table here and post the code then I can't help.  So you are left with using logger.log()

Comment: It was not made clear in your question that this snippet was being called by an onEdit trigger

Comment: `Bu` is undefined

Comment: range,col,row are all undefined

Comment: What sheet is this supposed to run on?

Comment: What is the problem it seems to be working for me

Comment: Your getting errors in your executions telling you that type.getValue() is not a function because type is  a date `var type = e.range.offset(0,-2).getValue();` Date() objects do not have a getValue() method

Comment: So all you need to do in to use the appropriate sheets and use the toasts to help you see where you are being taken and then look of errors in the execution logs and or use Logger.log to figure you errors.  It helps if you have this a lot because some of the errors are hard to see.

Comment: You probably need to go back and reset your sheet because I messed it up while I was playing with it.

Comment: Sheet is reset. Bu is declared as a constant at the beginning of the script.

Comment: Cooper, third paragraph, second sentence I clearly stated that it was part of an onEdit() function. You don't seem to want to help and I'm trying to learn here, so what are you getting at?

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I figured out the problem. In the snippet above, I was trying to use getValue() where it wasn't needed. The corrected lines are:

```
  if(type == w12){
    console.log('12 Weeks');
    due.setDate(due.getDate() + 84);
    range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due);
  }else if(type == annual){
    console.log('Annual');
    due.setFullYear(due.getFullYear() + 1);
    range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due);
  }else if(type == qtr){
    console.log('Quarterly');
    due.setMonth(due.getMonth() + 3);
    range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due);
  }else if(type == bia){
    console.log('Bi-Annual');
    due.setMonth(due.getMonth() + 6);
    range.offset(0,-1).setValue(due);
  }else if(type == once){
    console.log('Once')
    range.offset(0,-3).clearContent();
    range.offset(0,-2).clearContent();
    range.offset(0,-1).clearContent();
    range.offset(0,1).clearContent();
  }
```